# Jquery String remove everything - before - first - "\n" & first "\n"

Tags: jquery, string, removeall

I need to remove everything before first first "\n" incl. the "\n"
is there any possibility?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: post a sample string

Comment: @JJJ uhm yeah but i need to remove the "first" and before first.

Comment: @GAX Yes, the duplicate does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) regex(for matching anything other than newline).

```
 str.replace(/^[^\n]+\n/,'')
```

```js
var str = `abc
def
ghi`;

console.log(str.replace(/^[^\n]+\n/, ''))
```

---

Or split string by the newline character, get elements except first and rejoin it using newline character.

```
 str.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n')
```

```js
var str=`abc
def
ghi`;

console.log(str.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n'))
```

---

Or you can use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method by getting the index of first newline character using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof) method.

```
 str.slice(str.indexOf('\n'))
```

```js
var str = `abc
def
ghi`;

console.log(str.slice(str.indexOf('\n') + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! 
str.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n')
worked fine for me.

Comment: @GAX : glad to help you :)